# android capture portion of camera view

Tags: android, camera, crop

I come up to you because I have a big problem.

I would like to capture only a portion of the camera view. 
I basically want something like this :

[image: image1]

I tried to do the same with AndroidStudio, by adding a picture on the screen, here is the result :

[image: image2]

It's ugly but it was just to try. 
You basically need to put your face into the transparent area, and then click on "take picture". I would like the camera to not take the black part. 
How is it possible ? Is it possible to create a kind of mask for the camera ?

I have in mind that in this case, I'll need to take the entire picture and scale it correctly by software. But then, I have to do it differently for every screen sizes. It looks incredibly difficult.

Instead, is it possible to directly modify the cameraView (SurfaceView, or SurfaceHolder) so that I won't need the image, and the picture will automatically fit the "mask" because it's actually the only thing the camera see.

Have you got some clues ?

thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

The camera sees whatever enters its lens. You cannot "make" it see only a certain shape out of its normal rectangle (unless you tape some black paper over it :)). The cropping is always done after the picture is taken. The `SurfaceView` and `SurfaceHolder` are just tools to help you present the picture (which can be already modified, if you want it to) on the phone screen.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot mask camera capture. You can apply the mask to result. Note that often you get still picture at a resolution much higher than what you use for preview. And preview resolution is not the same as screen resolution (which you should use to put the black mask on the screen). In such case, your postprocessing mask should match the picture resolution and not the preview resolution.